# Delete own/personal chat history on discord code

Tags: message, discord, delete-file

Since discord doesn’t allow users to choose for a deletion of their messages sent throughout the several channels in which they posted, however allowing server moderators to delete those messages if they’re accompanied by a ban, I was wondering whether someone had scripted or knows of a script to do so.

So basically a script that deletes your messages you have sent in the different channels in one or multiple discord servers. Does anyone have an idea for that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this, is that the Discord API will only allow you to read back and delete 100 messages back, unless you clear the entire channel. The API also does not allow you to bulkDelete messages 2 weeks or older.

Well, first things first is this is an extremely broad question. This is something that would be done with a discord bot. Common libraries are: 
Discord.js (javascript): https://discord.js.org/#/ 
Discord4Java (java): https://github.com/Discord4J/Discord4J 
DiscordSharp (c#): https://github.com/suicvne/DiscordSharp

Developer docs: https://discordapp.com/developers/docs

Developer portal: https://discordapp.com/developers